# Upload CSV data directly to Amazon Redshift with Talend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, talend

Is it possible to upload data directly to Amazon Redshift without passing through Amazon S3 (Using Talend)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this using talend connectors for postgres, but the result would be very slow indeed (could be seconds per row of data). 
You really need to

1. split large csv files up e.g. 10MB each (no set number for this)
2. gzip each csv file
3. upload to s3
4. run a redshift copy command
5. run some sql on redshift if required to process the new data (upsert
   for example)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `INSERT` queries, but is not at all efficient, and very slow, and thus, not recommended. Redshift is built for handling and managing bulk loads.

Using `COPY` command to load data into Redshift after splitting the large files into smaller parts, using [multi-part file upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) to S3 and then loading the data from S3 to Redshift using COPY command, in parallel ([see this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading-data-from-S3.html)), is the best and fastest approach to load data into Redshift.